# How to create a new version of each Azure secret stored in a text file using Azure CLI

Tags: azure

I need help please on creating a script to read from a text file to get the names of Azure secrets and then set the attributes of each secret. The most important thing of all is setting the value of a secret using a loop.

Comment: What azure secrets? Is it key vault secrets?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to Azure skey vault secrets. I need to create a new version of the secrets since I cannot update the existing ones and set their values, and properties.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a new version of the secrets since I cannot update the existing ones and set their values and properties.

You can use the script below to update the secret version of Azure Key Vault secrets from the name that you stored in a text document.

**Script:**

```
$keyVaultName = "your-keyvault-name"
$secretNamesFile = "xxxx\sample.txt"
$newSecretValue = "new-secret-value"
 
# Loop through the secret names in the text file
Get-Content $secretNamesFile | ForEach-Object {
    $secretName = $_.Trim()

    # Get the current version of the secret
    try {
        $currentSecretId = (az keyvault secret show --name $secretName --vault-name $keyVaultName --query "id" -o tsv).Trim()
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Secret not found: $secretName"
        continue
    }

    # Create a new version of the secret
    az keyvault secret set --name $secretName --vault-name $keyVaultName --value $newSecretValue

    # Set the attributes of the new version of the secret
    az keyvault secret set-attributes --id $currentSecretId --enabled true
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "created": "2024-01-12T05:27:39+00:00",
    "enabled": true,
    "expires": null,
    "notBefore": null,
    "recoverableDays": 90,
    "recoveryLevel": "Recoverable+Purgeable",
    "updated": "2024-01-12T05:27:39+00:00"
  },
  "contentType": null,
  "id": "https://venkatvault1.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret-1/6acxxxx",
  "kid": null,
  "managed": null,
  "name": "secret-1",
  "tags": {
    "file-encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "value": "new-secret-value"
}
```

**Portal:**
[image: Azure Key Vault Portal]

**Reference:**
[az keyvault secret | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-set-attributes).

**Update:**

As you mentioned in the comment here is the Bash script to update the secret version of Azure Key Vault secrets from the name that you stored in a text document.

```
keyVaultName="keyvaultname"
secretNamesFile="./sample.txt"
newSecretValue="new-secret-value"

# Loop through the secret names in the text file
while read -r secretName; do
    secretName=$(echo "$secretName" | xargs) # Trim leading/trailing whitespace
    currentSecretId=$(az keyvault secret show --name "$secretName" --vault-name "$keyVaultName" --query "id" -o tsv 2>/dev/null)

    if [ -z "$currentSecretId" ]; then
        echo "Secret not found: $secretName"
        continue
    fi

    az keyvault secret set --name "$secretName" --vault-name "$keyVaultName" --value "$newSecretValue"

    az keyvault secret set-attributes --id "$currentSecretId" --enabled true
done < "$secretNamesFile"
```

Comment: Hi Vinkatesan, How do I get the old secret value? I would like to get the old secret value and modify a small part of it. Then once the secret is modified I would like to set it as the new secret.

Comment: To get the old secret value you can use this command  `$currentSecretValue = az keyvault secret show --name <secret-name> --vault-name <keyvault-name> --query "value" -o tsv`

Comment: To modify `az keyvault secret set --name <secret-name> --vault-name <keyvault-name> --value <new-secret-value>`

Comment: Thanks Vinkatesan, It seems to work but I only ran the code to fetch the old secret attributes, I did not yet run the second command which will set the secret value. Normally when I create a new version of the secret via the Azure portal instead of using the Azure CLI, I didn't have to worry about those attributes. When I set the new secret value using the command you showed above, will it automatically set the attributes such as the expiration date and the id?

Comment: I spoke too soon only a few lines worked in Bash CLI. I copied a couple lines from your code then executed them individually and they seemed to work. However, when I tried running your code in its entirety, it threw a bunch of command not found errors. It says the commands Get-Content $secretNamesFile and ForEach-Object are not found. It also complained that "id" and "name" which it said expects an argument and each. It also says there there is syntax error near an unexpected token "}" . I don't think some of the commands you provided are Bash commands but instead are Powershell commands.

Comment: Check the updated answer, Hope this addressed your comments.